# Entity Relationship Diagram for Timetable management system

Tags: sql, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have to create a database of timetable management system but before implementation I've decided to create ER diagram and relational model accordingly. 
[Here is the diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zN4H.png) All the users can belong to one or more departments. Some of the users belong to the courses, means, Lecturers, students and head of schools are associated with specific courses (can be more than one course). The course itself contains class which has information about when and where the class is going to be. All the users have access to timetables. Role attribute in users entity indicates if the user is admin or not.  I wonder if this logic and the representation with ER diagram is correct or not.

Note: I'm hesitant about the INFO entity. Will it be better if I will get rid of it and show all the attributes of INFO in Contains Relationship,which integrates Course, Class and timetable?

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Basics design questions are going to be faqs.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the goal of your task and the database system/programming environment where you are going to implement this...

You are probably better off leaving it as is if you are looking for a [1st Normal Form (1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

In reality you are often accepting some redundancies to speed up processing and minimize work efforts. So, this would be an argument for following you suggestion to not have the INFO and show the attricbutes in the other entities. Unfortunatily, thats usually not what teachers are looking for in a 101 type course... ...but it could be a good alternative solution in case the solution is too slow and difficult to implement ...